# Protractor - Connect to MS SQL management studio- Is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ssms, protractor

I need to validate lots of data at the backend for my Protractor(Jasmine framework) tests. We use Microsoft SQL server Management studio. How do I connect to the database in my protractor tests? Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Is this what I need? It says it is still not ready. Has anyone used it?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sqlserver

Answer (score 3):

There is one that seems to be production ready: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

One thing to note is that MS-SQL Management Studio is an IDE for MS-SQL Server which is the database server itself. The package above allows you to connect to the server from a NodeJS environment and query the database which is what you need to verify that some data is inserted correctly.

Please keep in mind that what you do here is an integration test while protractor is an end-to-end test framework. Possibly there is a better way to do the job you need to do, depending on the technology you use behind your application.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and see if I can make progress. Validating data at the backend is critical part of some of our tests. We use .Net for the server side and front end is all angularJS, Do let me know if there is anything else you can suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely possible, 
you can refer, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Code to connect : -

Config::

```
var config = {
        server: 'YOURSERVER',
        database: 'YOURDB',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'pwd',
        port: 1433,
        options: {
            instanceName: 'DBinstance',
            encrypt: true
        }
    };
```

use encrypt: true only if your server has SSL running on it. I used default port in the above config, you can use your port number.

```
var conn = new this.sql.Connection(this.config);
        var req = new this.sql.Request(conn);
        conn.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;

            }
            req.query("Select 1 as Number", function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(recordset);
                }
                conn.close();
            });

        });
```